# MATLAB Size equivalent function in python

Tags: python, matlab, data-structures, cell

hI i have a code in matlab. Based on my understanding I have translated that code to python. Can someone let me know if it is the right way to translate.

```
for i = 1:length(Filters)
    Filters{i} = gpuArray(2*(single(sign(Filters{i}))-0.5));
    NumLearntWeightsEachLayer(i) = size(Filters{i},3)*size(Filters{i},4)*4;
end
NumLearntWeightsEachLayer(end) = size(Filters{end},3)*size(Filters{end},4);
NumLearntWeightsEachLayer
TotalLearntWeights = sum(NumLearntWeightsEachLayer)
```

Could someone let me know if this could be an equivalent code for the for loop here.

```
for i in range (1,Filters):
    Filters(i) = (2* (Filters(i) - 0.5))
    NumLearntWeightsEachLayer(i) = (Filters(i),3).shape * (Filters(i),4).shape *4
```

I also want to know what could be the right translation for the last part of the code

```
 NumLearntWeightsEachLayer(end) = size(Filters{end},3)*size(Filters{end},4);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good start.. some small fixes -

```
for i in range (0,len(Filters)):
    for j in range(0, len(Filters[i]):
        Filters[i][j] = 2*(round(Filters[i][j],1) - 0.5)
    NumLearntWeightsEachLayer[i] = len(Filters[i][3])*len(Filters[i][4])*4
```

For the last line-

```
NumLearntWeightsEachLayer(end) = size(Filters{end},3)*size(Filters{end},4);
```

It can be written as -

```
NumLearntWeightsEachLayer[-1] = len(Filters[-1][3])*len(Filters[-1][4]);
```

Comment: Should i add length for NumLearntWeightsEachLayer[i] = len(Filters[i][3])*len(Filters[i][4])*4 and also wanted to know what would be the replacement for a n unsigned value.

Comment: Yeah.. length will be added for NumLearntWeightsEachLayer[i] = len(Filters[i][3])*len(Filters[i][4])*4 . I edited in my answer. 

Can you please rephrase this question? I am not entirely sure I understand it.
"what would be the replacement for a n unsigned value"

Comment: in this line of code  Filters{i} = gpuArray(2*(single(sign(Filters{i}))-0.5)); it has mentioned single value and signed integer. How to translate it in python. In python will it consider signed value by default?

Comment: Check the edit for single precision value.
Here sign function is the signum function in MATLAB?

Comment: Hi I tried to print the value of NumLearntWeightsEachLayer. Unfortunately I am not able to get any output!!